# Switching from mysql_ to PDO

Tags: pdo

After a lot of recommendation from others I have decided to make the switch from mysql_ to PDO. I started looking at PDO literally around 15 minutes ago and I'm stuck trying to convert this line of code into PDO format.

```
function verify_user($username, $recover_password) {
        return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password_recovery` = '$recover_password'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

I have looked at a couple of tutorials and as far as I can work out I can do the actual query with this code:

```
$verify_user = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password_recovery` = '$recover_password'";
    $result = $con->prepare($verify_user);
    $result->execute();
```

The problem I am having is the second part of the line of code - the mysql_result. Now that the query has run I have no idea how to return true or false using PDO. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Updated:

```
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password_recovery` = :recover_password");
$result->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':password_recovery', $recover_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();
```

From reading that page you provided it would be:

```
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password_recovery` = :recover_password");
$result->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':password_recovery', $recover_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();
return  ($con->fetch($result) == 1) ? true : false;
```

I'm probably miles out but I appreciate the help you've given me :) I'll do a couple more searches.

Comment: You're using PDO wrong. `$username` and `$recover_password` should be placeholders, **NOT** directly inserted into the query string. As for retrieving the results, here's a hint: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I think this should be correct? (edited main post)

Comment: better with the parameters. wrong with the fetch. you're selecting a count, so you'll ALWAYS get back 1 row. you need to fetch that row's data and then check the count results.

Comment: Surely if the username and recovery code match the database then it will return a count of one, therefore verifying that it exists? If they don't match it won't count anything right? Sorry if I'm confusing you explaining this.

Comment: the count will return how many rows were matched. e.g. if the user/pass don't match, the count will be 0, but you'll get one row of result data. If the username/password DO match, then count will be 1, but you STILL get one row of data. e.g. you're not retrieving rows of user account data, you're retrieving a row that simply tells you how many rows were matched.

Comment: So I should change the SELECT COUNT to SELECT and then count how many rows are returned, or am I missing the point of what you are saying?

Comment: it's up to you. either just do a plain non-counting select, then use `$result->rowCount` to see how many rows you did get, or use count, fetch that one row, and see what the count is.

Answer (score -1):

I would write the function this way:

```
function verify_user($username, $recover_password) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS count FROM `users` 
        WHERE `username` = ? AND `password_recovery` = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($username, $recover_password));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { }  /* should be exactly one row anyway */
    return $row["count"] == 1;
}
```

There's no need to use `bind_param()`, since you can just pass values in an array argument to `execute()`.  And there's no need to specify the parameter type (that's actually ignored, at least in the MySQL PDO driver).

Also be careful to do error-checking. The `prepare()` and `execute()` functions return `false` on error.  Many things can cause an error.  You could misspell a column name.  Your database connection may lack the right database privileges.  Someone could drop the table.

FWIW, proper error-checking is important when using the *mysql_** and *mysqli_** API's too, but it seems that few people do it right.

In the above code, I don't show checking the return values because I've made an assumption that we've enabled exceptions when we created the PDO connection.

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

That relieves us of having to write code to check the return values every time, but it means that an error will cause our application to go "white-screen".  It's best practice to handle the exceptions in the caller function, and display some friendly error screen.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter: what do you think is missing in my answer?  Perhaps I can improve it.